# Zombie Island of Dr.Ned spawn point

Tags: borderlands, borderlands-zombie-island-of-dr-ned

Every time I start the game with my character in Jakobs Cove, I start at the very beginning of the zone (the point you start from when you first Fast Travel in), regardless of where I quit and saved from earlier. Am I missing something obvious here, or is this the only new-u station in the area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jakobs Cove is the only new-u station however the Windmill actually becomes unlocked after a certain point and allows you to use it as a shortcut to get to the town faster. Also, some of the gates that are blocked off if you take the long way around open up later as well, allowing quicker access to other areas of the island.

Comment: Ok, at least I know I'm not doing something wrong. It seems strange to me to only have one new-u there when they were so common in the main game.

Comment: @Raven13 its is also a relatively small area compared to the main game

Comment: Also, if you're playing multiplayer spawning there means you can jump to any new U station to meet up with other players